# Is it possible for macOS to handle a scheduled local notification?

Tags: objective-c, macos

Please note that I am referring to macOS, and to *scheduled* local notifications. I want for the application to be able to handle when the notification is *presented*, not when the user actually taps the notification.

UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate has methods for handling a notification when the app is in the *foreground*:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenterdelegate/1649518-usernotificationcenter?language=objc

However it appears there is no way to handle one that is presented when the application is in the *background*

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Well, let's not forget that, unlike iOS, a macOS app running in the background is _running_. So it can just watch the clock.

Comment: Yes, however an app can schedule a notification, then the app could be restarted before the notification is presented. It would need to retrieve pending notifications when it starts and keep track of the time for each. I just figured the system might be able to notify the application, like it does when it is in the foreground.